# VSCode Python version defaults to 2.7 in the integrated terminal no matter what I do

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm running VSCode `1.36.0` on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6.

When I use the integrated terminal in VSCode and run Python it always runs Python 2.7 from `/usr/bin/python` on MacOS  instead of the default anaconda Python. If I do the same in the system terminal everything is fine.

I've looked at the answers in these two related questions:

[Why Is macOS Visual Studio Code Using Wrong Python Interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640176/why-is-macos-visual-studio-code-using-wrong-python-interpreter)

[How can I change python version in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-python-version-in-visual-studio-code)

I'm not running the code-runner extension. I've updated the `python.pythonPath` setting to point to Anaconda Python and yet no matter what I do, `which python` in the integrated terminal returns `/usr/bin/python`. Selecting a different conda environment with `conda activate myenv` doesn't do anything either.

Haven't experienced this issue before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get the shell path of your default terminal by executing `echo $SHELL`
this should output something like `/bin/bash`

now check if the VSCode integrated Terminal points to the same shell and if not, set the integrated shell of VSCode to the one of your terminal.

Edit (to provide the full solution):

vsCode runs every new shell as login shell 
so if you set the Anaconda Path in `.bashrc` it will not be set in the integrated shell. 
If this is the case, you can set `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": []` to force vsCode to run a non Login shell and load `.bashrc`

Comment: Both the integrated terminal and the system terminal return `/bin/bash`

Comment: vsCode runs every new shell as login shell so if you set the Anaconda Path in `.bashrc` it will not be set in the integrated shell.
If this is the case, you can set `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": []` to force vsCode to run a non Login shell and load `.bashrc`

Comment: Thank you so much @skat! Was facing this problem for months. Had to use default terminal for months. Now I can use integrated terminal!.